# Broadcasting matrix-vector dot product

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, broadcast

I have a set of matrices collected in a 3-D array with shape `(1222, 47, 47)`, and a set of vectors in a 2-D array with shape `(1222, 47)`.

Is there a broadcasting way to multiply each [47x47] matrix with its corresponding [47] vector?  With a full loop, this would be

```
numpy.vstack([A[n, :, :].dot(xb[n, :]) for n in range(A.shape[0])])
```

which is okay for 1222 elements, but I might have a lot more later.  I tried if `dot`, `matrix_multiply`, `inner`, or `inner1d` would fit the bill, in combination with `transpose`, but I didn't quite get it.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of these should do it:

```
matrix_multiply(matrices, vectors[..., None])
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', matrices, vectors)
```

None will take advantage of a highly optimized library though.

Sometime in the future, when [PEP 465](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) has been implemented, using Python >= 3.5 you should be able to simply do:

```
matrices @ vectors[..., None]
```

Comment: +1 for a great answer, just out of curiosity, how do you know neither solution uses optimized library?

Comment: Ah, I missed that I needed to add the newaxis.  One note: the colloquial way to add a new axis should be `np.nexaxis`, isn't it's value `None` just a temporary implementation detail?

Comment: I think it is more than simply an implementation detail. The docs do say that `None` can be used instead of `newaxis`, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), so I think that sort of makes it part of the API.

Comment: @CTZhu I more or less know the source code, `einsum` will use SIMD operations if your processor supports them, `matrix_multiply` is just a vanilla C implementation, neither of them uses BLAS even if it is available.